# Specify a prefix for the src tag in index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In using angular-cli and ng build to build my project, I have a couple of questions.

1. The container that I'm running the angular screen in I need to put a prefix in front of the src tags in the script tag.  so src="styles.bundle.js" needs to be src="/my/prefix/styles.bundle.js".  Is there a way to do this command line, and not a manual edit?  I tried to set the base href, but that did not seem to help.
2. If I have no production specific environment changes, is there any difference between dev & production builds.

Comment: Could you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

Working well for us using this

```
ng build --deploy-url=prefixfolder
```

Comment: This works in most cases, but it doesn't seem to work when you add your own `link` tags to index.html, nor does it seem to work for the `favicon`. Anyone find a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

1. This sounds strange. The `ng build --output-path /my/prefix/` should generate proper base href for the `index.html`. Strange if it doesn't.
2. AFAIK, the production build has more optimizations turned on. Thus it results in a smaller bundle. You can test your particular app's size w/ and w/o `-prod`.

Comment: I am positive the reference is not working the way I am deploying it without editing it